# What do you call a sentence with words that sound the same or rhyme?

Tags: word-request

> How much wood could a woodchuck chuck If a woodchuck could chuck wood?
> As much wood as a woodchuck could chuck, If a woodchuck could chuck
> wood.

What do you call a sentence with words that sound the same or rhyme? Is there a word for it? I would think so, and would a sentence with several rhymes have a similar word for it, or is it the same word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The everyday word for this is a *tongue twister*.

Depending on the type of similar sounds used, it might more technically be called *alliteration*.